# What is the use of Cpython , IronPython , Jython ? Is it used in the process of code conversion from Python to Machine code?

Tags: python-3.x, jython, cpython

I heard about python only but when I see different names on search result than I confused what the hell is this but I taught may be it is used in the part of code conversion but not sure about it what actually these are ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is a language. CPython, IronPython, Jython are different implementations of this langauge. They also all happen to be implemented in different languages themselves: CPython is written in C, IronPython in .NET, and Jython in Java. Thus, it is very easy to integrate IronPython into a .NET program, and it is really easy to embed Jython into a Java program. But for the most part, when people execute Python, they are running their Python code through CPython (even if they don't know that's what it's officially called). It is the original Python implementation, it is the fastest of them, as well as being the implementation that defines what Python is. Unless you want to use Python within .NET or Java frameworks, you might never encounter the other two.